# Nlog Logger.Info not working

Tags: nlog

i have a webservice which is consumed via jquery ... now the problem is i want to put some debug into from nlog so that i can see how the flow is actually going .. i thought nlog's option for debuging ....
here is my config and code

```
<targets>
<target name="file" xsi:type="File"
    layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}"
    fileName="${basedir}/Logs/${shortdate}.log" />
</targets>

<rules>
<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file"  />
<logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="file" />
<logger name="*" minlevel="Fatal" writeTo="file" />
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
</rules>
```

and the logger class where i have given for getting debug information is

```
[ScriptService]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    [WebMethod]
    public String GetAgentDetails(String AgentId)
    {
        logger.Info("This is webservice");
        String result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            using (ISession session = NhibernateHelper.Opensession())
            {
                logger.Info("Enters Session");
                 var agent = GetAgent(); // Gets the agent object
                 result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(agent);
                 logger.Info(result);
                 return result;
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
        {
            logger.Error(ioe.Message);
            logger.Fatal(ioe.Message);
            logger.Error(ioe.InnerException);
            logger.Fatal(ioe.InnerException);
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex.Message);
            logger.Fatal(ex.Message);
            logger.Error(ex.InnerException);
            logger.Fatal(ex.InnerException);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

when accessed through the jquery script it should have written the log informations where i have written logger.info(result) but it seems no log file is created .can someone explain whats the problem ? however the same log file works for all other classes . no issues in that . if exceptions are thrown the log file gets created and log is written. but in this case for logger.info its not happening . i am using Nlog 2.0 with Asp.net 3.5 SP1 .

Comment: does [this](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file#Troubleshooting_logging) help?

Comment: i have looked into it .. but i need to actually log it . in fact as u see above i have already configured it as per you have given the link . but my problem is that the logger.info(message) is not working as per expectation. i dont find the log file being created and the info message being written there :(